# バッジの分析的について

Tags: サポート, 完了, バッジ

バッジの中にある、「分析的」バッジについて質問です。

このバッジは括弧で終了と書かれており、意味が掴めません。
恐らく、元のStackOverFlowで以前あったバッジが持っているユーザーの為に残っていて、そのままこちらにも来てしまったのかと考えています。

このバッジの意味、もしくは自分の考え通りの物であるならば今後どうなるかを教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: StackOverflowの [analytical](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/77/analytical) バッジ説明文では"〜 (retired)"となっていますので、確かに現在は新規取得できないバッジのようです。

Comment: 昔はFAQを読んだら獲得ができましたが、行っている通りに今はもらえないですね。削除できるかどうかを確認します。

Comment: @jmac 私の意見では、ここは出来たばかりなので新しい人にFAQを読んでもらう事が重要と思います。そのためバッジを削除ではなく、一時的にでも取得可能なバッジにする事を考えてもらえませんか？

Comment: @rizaudo 2013年までヘルプセンターはありませんでした。代わりに1ページのFAQがありました。追加が多かったため「ワンページ」と言いながら、セクション等が多く、読みきれるサイズではなかったため、現在「ヘルプセンター」に変えました。ヘルプセンターは複数のページがあるため、一つだけを読み切ると前のFAQより情報量が少ないです。そのため、バッジをヘルプからツアーに変えました。FAQとヘルプセンターのコードも異なるため、昔のバッジを簡単にオンはできませんので、古いバッジをリタイアされました。言ってる通りにヘルプが大事ですが、現在の構造ではヘルプのためのバッジは難しいです。

Answer (score 2):

現在は、「廃止されたバッジ」と[表示される](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)ようになっています。

[image]